# How to generate an OSGI module with maven?

Tags: java, maven, osgi

Is it possible to generate a OSGI Module with maven?
Usually I can generate a project like

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.my.company \
  -DartifactId=hello-world
```

Is there a similar way to get an OSGI module?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure. Probably the archetypes are a bit outdated. I simply create a normal maven project and add the [bnd-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/maven/bnd-maven-plugin) at the parent ([see here for an example](https://github.com/cschneider/osgi-chat/blob/master/pom.xml#L101-L124)).

Alternatively you can use the maven-bundle-plugin. [See here](https://github.com/apache/aries-rsa/blob/master/parent/pom.xml#L227-L251).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
    <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>bnd-process</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With this present all your modules will be bundles. If you need to tune the Manifest settings then you create a bnd.bnd file in your module. You can edit this by hand or with the bndtools bnd file editor.